# View overlapping nofication

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I would be grateful if anyone could tell me how can I find out that one of my subviews is overlapped by anything (I mean some alerts or something like that)

Answer (score 2):

you can view itself in xcode while running the app.  Follow these steps.

1. Run the app in simulator.
2. Select xcode window and Go to **debug** from top menu bar and select **Capture view Hierarchy**

[image]

3. Here you can see your complete view structure.

Comment: Sorry but what should I do if I want to this in my app programmatically. I need to know when some view is covered by another one and is not visible?

Answer (score 1):

Use following code..

```
- (void)checkAnyViewOverlappingViewFrame:(UIView*)view topLevelView:(UIView *)toplevelview viewToSearch:(UIView*)viewtosearch {

    // Get the subviews of the view
    NSArray *subviews = [viewtosearch subviews];

    // Return if there are no subviews
    if ([subviews count] == 0) return; // COUNT CHECK LINE

    for (UIView *subview in subviews) {

        CGRect frameRelativeToParent = [subview convertRect:subview.bounds
                                                       toView:toplevelview];

        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(view.frame, frameRelativeToParent) && view.layer.zPosition < subview.layer.zPosition) {

            NSLog(@"Overlapping view: %@", subview);
        }

        [self checkAnyViewOverlappingViewFrame:view topLevelView:toplevelview viewToSearch:subview];
    }
}
```

Here `view` is your subviews to check. In `toplevelview` pass `self.view` which parent view of all views. In `viewtosearch` pass `self.view`